Kaplan Meier analysis - what to do with simultaneous event and censoring
I'm running time to event analysis on a database of patients.  In a very few cases, patients were censored AND had the event of interest (a new diagnosis) on the same day, but each patient in my dataframe should only be counted once with either a censoring event (0) or a diagnosis event (1).  In those cases, how do you chose whether to count them has having been censored on that day or diagnosed?  They could be logged with a diagnosis then censored (dropping ou), or the diagnosis could be erroneous...  Are there any papers that deal with this situation?
